# pyqt: How to use a same function to set text of different qt widget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, signals-slots

I am new to both Qt and python. It may be a easy question to most of your guy, but I can't find it on Google.
I have a form, with different sets of  "path and button" combinations.
click each path it would open a QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() dialog, and setText to the lineEdit.

My questions is how to write a function like this:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(btn1, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), set_widge_text(lineEdit1))
QtCore.QObject.connect(btn2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), set_widge_text(lineEdit2))
QtCore.QObject.connect(btn3, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), set_widge_text(lineEdit3))
```

in function:

```
def set_widge_text(self, widget_name)
      widget_name.setText("self.fname")

def open_file_dialog(self):
     fname = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',
             './')
     self.fname = fname
```

Is there anyway to achieve this? I don't want to write different sets of set_widge_text() just for different lineEdits, any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the signals using a `lambda`:

```
    btn1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_file_name(lineEdit1))
    btn2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_file_name(lineEdit2))
    btn3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_file_name(lineEdit3))

def set_file_name(self, edit):
    edit.setText(self.open_file_dialog())

def open_file_dialog(self):
    return QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', './')
```

Comment: thanks, it actually work! Just small typo on your code edit.setText(self.open_file_name()) should be edit.setText(self.open_file_dialog())

Answer (score 0):

In Qt (sorry, not familiar w/ PyQt) there's a couple of things to think about:

First, your signal & slot must take the same arguments.  So the above won't work.  set_widget_text() must take no arguments, as clicked() does not.

You can always tell what QObject emitted a signal inside the slot by casting sender() to the appropriate class.  In this case, in Qt it would be:

```
QPushButton* myButton = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>( sender() );
```

I'm not sure how the casting would work in PyQt, but there should be a similar solution.  From there you should be able to figure out what dialog to open.  if QPushButton::text() doesn't work, you can use a simple associative array to map a string to each button when you initialize the buttons.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I would consider using it when I use c++ interface of Qt.